# Angular2 Router - canActivate is redirecting with post request

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

Implemented CanActivate to guard the routes, and navigating to /login if the user is not logged in, but i can see it is redirecting with POST request, which results to 404 error.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate() {
        console.log("canActivate : AuthGuard");
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: Browser Console]

If i remove AuthGuard it is redirecting properly. Can any body help me.

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {DashBoardComponent} from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes =  [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashBoardComponent }
            ]
    }
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ,routing , CKEditorModule,FormsModule, HttpModule, ReactiveFormsModule, TagInputModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent , DashBoardComponent,LoginComponent,HomeComponent],
  providers: [AuthGuard, AuthenticationService, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

import {DashBoardComponent} from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    precompile: [LoginComponent]

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("checkking ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your server support HTML5 pushState? Can you try to enable `HashLocationStrategy` and reproduce the problem?

Comment: can you also include the component code and routerLink part..

Comment: even after adding HashLocationstrategy, same issue.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few tips to check:

1. Check RouterModule.forRoot and RouterModule.forChild routing configurations are defined correct.
2. Check for the default URL that is being triggered.
3. Check for button click event, whether the router is being used to navigate to next page instead of using the default behaviour of form button (incase you are using forms)

Comment: Thanks Ashwin, form sumbit is causing the issue. Resolved it by removing the form tag.